# Make project automatically makes IntelliJ IDEA very slow. Any workaround?

Tags: eclipse, performance, ide, intellij-idea, usability

I tried to use the "Eclipse mode" to do the *build in background*, in order to identify compilation error while refactoring:

[image]

but IDEA becomes so slow!

Any workaround?

I already tried the IDEA way of compiling and it's not for me: for the first time in ages I am breaking the builds... (and I need to double check from the command line with mvn-compile before to git-push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Mode plug-in is known to cause performance issues, uninstall it. `Make project automatically` should not affect IDE performance. If it's slow, [provide a CPU snapshot](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-192).